# Example for a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{L}^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence, uniform-integrability

I am looking for an example of a sequence of functions $(g_n)$ that is in $\mathcal{L}^1[0,1]$ and U.I. so that the following three conditions are satisfied:

> $\forall \, n\, \, \vert g_n \vert \leq 1 \text{ a.e.}, \Vert g_n \Vert_1 \geq {1 \over10} \text{ and } \forall \, E \subset [0,1] \text{ and measurable}, \, \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E g_n = 0$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're looking for a sequence of functions $g_n$ which converges weakly but not in $L^1$. A standard example is $g_n(x) = \sin (2 \pi n x)$- you should work out the properties for yourself.

One note: due to the bounded convergence theorem, if $\{g_n\}$ are all bounded from above by 1, then the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: How to prove the third property?

Comment: Think about the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: Can the condition be strengthened to $\vert g_n \vert = 1$ a.e

Comment: @pondy $g_n(x) = e^{i n x}$ will also work.

Comment: I am trying to verify the second property, and as the value of $n$ increases the number of spikes in the $\sin(nx)$ increases. So i dont see how the norm will be greater than $.1$ for every $n$. I know I am missing some thing, not sure what it is

Comment: @pondy Try $g_n(x) = \sin (2 \pi n x)$. Then using the change of variables $x \rightarrow x / n$ you can see that $\|g_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{2 \pi n} |\sin x| dx = \int_0^{2 \pi} |\sin x| dx$ for any $n$, i.e. $\|g_n\|_1$ is constant.

Comment: One last question about the $\vert g_n \vert = 1$ a.e. Can it be done in the real field. I figured out the function has to take $1$ or $-1$ a.e. and discontinuous.

Comment: @pondy Yes, you can. Define $r : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ so that $r(x) = 1$ for $x \in [k, k+1/2)$ and $r(x) = -1$ for $x \in [k + 1/2, k + 1)$, where $k$ ranges over the integers. This is a 'square wave' and is known as Rademacher's function to some. Now take $g_n(x) = r(n x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your patient replies